# html nested collapse no bootstrap, jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a nested collapse. I saw this from webschool. As you can see nested collapse is inside it. But when it is inside it won't expand. I'm going to do a nested collapse inside nested collapse inside nested collapse (3 or 4 times eventually)

If you guys know a better way you do not have to follow the code below Thanks.

No `bootstrap` please and no `jQuery` only pure `html/css` `vanilla js`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>


<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>test ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't even need javascript :) https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You internal expandable field is expanding but is blocked by the surrounding maxheight of its parent.

One way would be to include all the containing contents heights when expanding the parent. Else you could add to it for the parent when expanding the child.

Ill show the first option below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>


<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>test ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      var childrensHeight = Array.from(content.querySelectorAll(".content")).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.scrollHeight , 0);
      content.style.maxHeight = (content.scrollHeight + childrensHeight)+ "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem with this would this is too much `complicated` solution involving `arrays`. Simple solution to set the max Height according to your need and will be responsive as well.

Comment: Yes and as i mentioned above that is a solution that only works if you know the height of text in advance. Which in my experience is more or less never.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple set your `content` `max-height to 350px` (or what you like depending on the text content you have) instead of using `content.scrollHeight`

The reason it was not working is that you are setting the `maxHeight` to your parent but not its child element.

This will work for every other collapsible you add as well.

Run snippet below to see it working nicely.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = "350px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

  <p>A Collapsible:</p>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Collapsible Set:</p>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>test ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem with this would be if you want to have dynamic text that sometimes might be higher than 350px.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that the OP increase the height if he wishes too according to the text.

Comment: You canot always know that in advance if you are working with texts from a cms or external source. Also the height might wary depending on screen width. And if you use a too large height to overcompensate your animation will not be as smooth. Though ill admit your solution is the simpler one and in cases where you know the text size in advance might be the best one.

Comment: @Achtung You do not make assumptions when answering whether what system it is CMS or etc etc. You provide a simple solution which will work for everyone and easily understandable and not complicating things with no assumptions.

Comment: I disagree i make no assumptions since my solution solves all situations. The asumptions are made when you provide a solution that will break in most real world scenarios.

Comment: a dynamic solution is always better than setting static heights

Answer (score 1):

## Without JS - fade animation, thanks to [Josh Brody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1937435/josh-brody).

Height transition is not possible with `<details>` ([view notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#Customizing_the_disclosure_widget)).

```css
details .collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

details > summary::-webkit-details-marker
{
  display: none;
}

details .collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

details[open] > .collapsible:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

details[open] > .collapsible,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

details .content {
  padding: 18px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-top: 0;
}

details[open] .content {
  animation: fade .2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>JS-Free Collapsibles - inspired by josh-brody!</h2>

<details>
  <summary class="collapsible">Collapsible A</summary>
  <div class="content">
    Some<br />
    Text<br />
    Here.<br />
    <br />
    
    <details>
      <summary class="collapsible">Collapsible B</summary>
      <div class="content">
          Read<br />
          My<br />
          Content!
      </div>
    </details>
    
  </div>
</details>
```

## Without JS - height transition

Good thing here is, you can place the `<label>` elements wherever you want, in case you want to trigger a collapse from elsewhere. You will have to take care of the ids though.

```css
.collapsible {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.collapsible label {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 18px;
  display: block;
}

.collapsible>label::after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible>input {
  display: none;
}

.collapsible>input:checked~label::after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.collapsible>input:checked~label,
.collapsible:hover>label {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible .content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-top: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 100% 0);
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

input:checked~.content {
  padding: 18px;
  height: auto;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}
```

```html
<h2>JS-Free Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<div class="collapsible">
  <input id="collapsible-a" type="checkbox" />

  <label for="collapsible-a">
    Collapsible A
  </label>

  <div class="content">
    Some<br /> Text
    <br /> Here.
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="collapsible">
      <input id="collapsible-b" type="checkbox" />

      <label for="collapsible-b">
        Collapsible B
      </label>

      <div class="content">
        Read<br /> My
        <br /> Content!
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

Some Text
```